# Funcionamiento del heap en C

Tags: c, punteros, manejo-de-memoria

Soy principiante en esto de la memoria dinámica en C, y estoy realizando pequeños programas para entender su funcionamiento. En este programa creo 2 punteros:

```
int *ptr_1 = (int *)calloc(100, sizeof(int));
char *ptr_2 = (char *)calloc(50, sizeof(char));
```

Y, según lo que entiendo debería pasar esto: Calloc crea 100 espacios de memoria, para guardar 100 enteros, los cuales son inicializados en 0. Entonces, el ptr_1 si empieza en 100, éste debería terminar en 500, porque hay 400 bytes reservados para 100 enteros. Entonces ptr_2 debería empezar en 504, ¿no? 4 bytes después del último entero. sin embargo mi programa dice esto:

```
printf("Puntero 1: %d\n", ptr_1);
for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    printf("Elemento: %3d, %d\n", i+1, (ptr_1 + i));
}
free(ptr_1);

printf("Puntero 2: %d\n", ptr_2);
free(ptr_2);
```

la dirección del primer elemento, dice (poniendo menos números de los que en verdad son evidentemente) 6816, el último elemento dice 7212, exactamente son 400 bytes reservados para 100 enteros. Pero el ptr_2 dice: 7224, es decir, 8 bytes después de los que según yo debería de haber. ¿Por qué sucede esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El [heap](https://codingornot.com/diferencias-entre-heap-y-stack) es una área de memoria donde los datos no se guardan de forma contigua, su contraparte es el *stack*.

Ahora, para hacer que la explicación sea más clara, modificaré un poco el código:

```c
int *ptr_1 = (int *)calloc(3, sizeof(int));

char *ptr_2 = (char *)calloc(3, sizeof(char));
```

En este caso se reserva memoria con la función *calloc*, en la cual, invoca una llamada al sistema operativo para encontrar un bloque de memoria contigua donde quepan los tres datos enteros.

Por lo tanto, internamente el heap puede quedar así:

```c
Bloque A:
Memory Address: 0x4 0x8 0x12
Datos:           0   0    0
```

Donde `ptr_1` quedaría apuntando a la dirección base del *bloque*, que en este caso sería `0x4`.

Entonces cuando invoques otra vez la función *calloc* para la reserva de tres datos de tipo `char`, no irá exactamente después de la última dirección del bloque `A` que reservamos anteriormente, porque en el *heap* los **bloques de memoria no son contiguos.**

Así que el segundo bloque puede estar así en el *heap:*

```c
                 Bloque A:                Bloque B:
Memory Address: 0x4 0x8 0x12 0x13 0x14 0x20 0x21 0x22
Datos:           0   0    0              0    0    0
```

Por lo tanto, el puntero `ptr_2` termina apuntando a la dirección `0x20`. Pero aquí empezamos a comprender que los datos de estos dos bloques no son contiguos, ya que puede tener espacios de memoria libre a su alrededor. En este caso, la dirección `0x13` y `0x14` son las zonas libres.

Su contraparte es el *stack*. Cada vez que invocas una función, se genera un pila por función, donde se guardan las variables locales, parámetros y la dirección de retorno (para volver al punto donde invocamos la función), sin embargo, en la [pila de llamadas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pila_(inform%C3%A1tica)) si tendrá todos los bloques contiguos y su acceso es mucho más rápido, porque lo hacemos por medio de un puntero que apunte al tope de la pila.

Imaginemos que tenemos este código:

```c
void foo(int a, int b)
{
    int c = 10;
}

int main(void)
{
     int d = 4, m = 2;
     foo(d, m);
     return 0;
}
```

Cuando se ejecute la función *main*, se crea un bloque en la pila, en la cual en memoria se podría reflejar así:

```c
Bloque A                 
Variable:  (d)    (m)
Dirección: 0x20  0x24
            4      2
```

Después cuando se ejecute la función `foo`, se vuelve a generar otra bloque en la pila:

```c
            Bloque A         Bloque B         
Variable:  (d)    (m)  (a)   (b)  (c)
Dirección: 0x20  0x24  0x32  0x36 0x40
Dato:       4      2     4    2    10
```

Y bueno, de esta manera es como se refleja el *stack* en memoria. Esto lo mencioné para que quede claro la diferencia entre el *heap* y *stack* y así comprender el funcionamiento del *heap*.

Sabiendo lo anterior, podemos responder a esta pregunta:

> > Entonces, el ptr_1 si empieza en 100, éste debería terminar en 500, porque hay 400 bytes reservados para 100 enteros. Entonces ptr_2 debería empezar en 504, ¿no? 4 bytes después del último entero.

**No.** El puntero `ptr_2` no apuntará después del último entero, porque el *heap* no funciona como una *stack* y esto se debe porque en el *stack* si sabemos cuantos bloques vamos a tener en memoria, por lo tanto, el compilador puede hacer que los bloques queden contiguos, sin embargo, con el *heap* no pasa esto, ya que la memoria puede crecer como decrecer (por algo se llama *memoria dinámica*).

**Fuente:**

- [Diferencias entre heap y stack.](https://codingornot.com/diferencias-entre-heap-y-stack)